# Haskell type length + 1

Tags: haskell

Could anyone help me to explain the type of length + 1 
I tried to type into ghci with following command `:t length + 1`
it returns `Num([a]->Int)=>[a]->Int`
what does this mean?
Thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the type of `+`:

```
> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

So both arguments have to be from the same instance of `Num`, and it returns one of those.  Then look at the type of `length`:

```
> :t length
length :: [b] -> Int
```

(Note that I've changed to use `b` here as the type variable, but it doesn't change the meaning).

So if you have `length + something`, then `length` must have a type that implements `Num`.  Since `length`'s type is already set as `[b] -> Int`, this means that `[b] -> Int` needs to be an instance of `Num`, and `something` would have to have the same type.  Since numeric literals in Haskell are polymorphic, this means that `1` can just has the type `Num a => a`, and the precise instance can be chosen by context.  Since in the expression `length + 1`, both arguments to `+` have to have the same type, this means that `1` has to have the same type as `length`, meaning that if we wrote out all the types explicitly we'd have something like

```
((+) :: Num ([b] -> Int) => ([b] -> Int) -> ([b] -> Int) -> ([b] -> Int))
    (length :: [b] -> Int)
    (1      :: [b] -> Int)
```

(Written in prefix form and split onto multiple lines so we can actually read it).

So basically, what this is saying is that in order to add something to `length`, you have to first define an instance of `Num` for `length`'s type.  The return type of `[b] -> Int` is just saying that it's returning something of the same type as `length`.

Is this useful?  No, almost certainly not.  It's a feature of Haskell's type system that you *can* write interesting and strange instances of `Num` for literally *any* type, but that does not mean that an instance of `Num` for every type is useful, definable in an intelligent way, or even possible without resorting to `undefined`.

---

We could write an instance for `Num` for this type, but I'll choose to write it inside a `newtype` because it lets us avoid language extensions.

```
newtype Silly a = Silly { unSilly :: [a] -> Int }

instance Num (Silly a) where
    fromInteger x = Silly $ const (fromInteger x)
    Silly f + Silly g = Silly $ \l -> f l + g l
    Silly f * Silly g = Silly $ \l -> f l * g l
    negate (Silly f) = Silly $ negate . f
    abs (Silly f) = Silly $ abs . f
    signum (Silly f) = Silly $ signum . f
```

Then we can use it as

```
> (unSilly $ Silly length + 1) [1, 2, 3]
4
> (unSilly $ Silly length * Silly length) [1, 2, 3, 4]
16
> (unSilly $ negate $ Silly length) [1, 2, 3]
-3
```

But this isn't really useful, it adds quite a bit of boilerplate to do something equivalent to

```
> length [1, 2, 3] + 1
4
> length [1, 2, 3, 4] * length [1, 2, 3, 4]
16
> negate $ length [1, 2, 3]
-3
```

Although in some examples are kind of cool:

```
> (unSilly $ Silly head + Silly last) [10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
15
```

But this only works on lists of type `[Int]`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helps me fully understand haskell type. Actually, length + 1 is an expression of (+), then length need to be limited to Num instance. We put Num([a]->Int) to implement this. Furthermore, we also need a para and a return value thus we put [a]-> Int here. Right?

Comment: if we want to use this. For example let f = length + 1. Then how could I use  f here?

Comment: @XiaotongYang Using the instance I defined, if you had `f = Silly length + 1`, then you could use `f` as `(unSilly f) some_list`, where `some_list` is a list.  (`Silly` and `unSilly` are just to wrap up the type as distinct so we don't have to use the `FlexibleInstances` extension, so you can pretty much treat them as something to make the types nicer nothing more.)  Then `f` would contain a function that calculates the length of a list and adds 1 to it.

Comment: I'm wondering how `1 :: [a] -> Int` is possible at all, it seems to have the wrong "kind" (I'm not sure if I'm using the term precisely here).  Is it thanks to the `fromInteger` function (given `Num ([a] -> Int)`)?

Comment: @Bolo it has the correct kind, in that the type can not accept any more type variables. It works because numeric literals are polymorphic, and the `fromInteger` is what does that. Essentially, the literal `1` gets replaced with `fromInteger 1` internally by the compiler. Since this is required when defining `Num`, you can always turn a literal into your own custom type.

Comment: @bheklilr I am also wondering what the type of "error" is. `:t error "something"` it returned `error "something"::a` what does a mean? Anything?