# What is '(Floating a, Num (a -> a))' in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, I just know that

```
:type ((+)(1))
((+)(1)) :: Num a => a -> a
((+)(1） 2
3
```

But how about

```
:type abs(sqrt)
abs(sqrt) :: (Floating a, Num (a -> a)) => a -> a
```

Actually, I try many times but fail to use the function 'abs(sqrt)'. Then I have a few questions. What is the type(class?) '(Floating a, Num (a -> a))'? Is it possible to use the function 'abs(sqrt)'? How?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like you've never bothered to check out the basic introduction to Haskell. I honestly wonder what made you think that `abs(sqrt)` would work and what made you use such a syntax.

Comment: @OtosakaYuu: it's `abs sqrt` not `abs(sqrt)` — the latter is misleading to both you and some other people; same about `((+1)(1))` which is actually jus t`((+) 1)` (no parens around the the `1`), and operator sections simplifies that to `(1 +)` even. Knowing and adhering to these sorts of rules will lead to a better understanding of Haskell, and clean, idiomatic, professional looking code.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Please follow SO guidelines and avoid comments like that. Please be welcoming and helpful to new users. If a question doesn't meet the expected standards, please provide constructive feedback to the user on how to improve it, and/or edit the question to make it better. Please avoid formulations like "it seems like you've never bothered to check..." and "I honestly wonder what made you think that" since they easily come-off as arrogant and dismissive. Instead, please bring forward any feedback in a direct and non-condescending way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A type class is a way to generalize functions so that they can be polymorphic and others can implement those functions for their own types.  Take as an example the type class `Show`, which in a simplified form looks like

```
class Show a where
    show :: a -> String
```

This says that any type that implements the `Show` typeclass can be converted to a `String` (there's some more complication for more realistic constraints, but the point of having `Show` is to be able to convert values to `String`s).

In this case, the function `show` has the full type `Show a => a -> String`.

If we examine the function `sqrt`, its type is

```
> :type sqrt
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

And for `abs`:

```
> :type abs
abs :: Num b => b -> b
```

If you ask GHCi what the types are it will use the type variable `a` in both cases, but I've used `b` in the type signature for `abs` to make it clear that these are different type variables of the same name, and it will help avoid confusion in the next step.

These type signatures mean that `sqrt` takes a value whose type implements the `Floating` typeclass (use `:info Floating` to see all the members) and returns a value of that same type, and that the `abs` function takes a value whose type implements the `Num` typeclass and returns a value of that same type.

The expression `abs(show)` is equivalently parsed as `abs sqrt`, meaning that `sqrt` is the first and only argument passed to `abs`.  However, we just said that `abs` takes a value of a `Num` type, but `sqrt` is a function, not a number.  Why does Haskell accept this instead of complaining?  The reason can be seen a little more clearly when we perform substitution with the type signatures.  Since `sqrt`'s type is `Floating a => a -> a`, this must match the argument `b` in `abs`'s type signature, so by substituting `b` with `Floating a => a -> a` we get that `abs sqrt :: (Floating a, Num (a -> a)) => a -> a`.

Haskell actually allows the function type to implement the `Num` typeclass, you could do it yourself although it would likely be nonsensical.  However, just because something wouldn't seem to make sense to GHC, so long as the types can be cleanly solved it will allow it.

You can't really use this function, it just doesn't really make sense.  There is no built-in instance of `Num (a -> a)` for any `a`, so you'd have to define your own.  You can, however, *compose* the functions `abs` and `sqrt` using the composition operator `.`:

```
> :type abs . sqrt
abs . sqrt :: Floating c => c -> c
```

And this does make sense.  This function is equivalent to

```
myfunc x = abs (sqrt x)
```

Note here that `x` is first applied to `sqrt`, and then the result of that computation is passed to `abs`, rather than passing the function `sqrt` to `abs`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I fully understand it now. Haskell type is so interesting:)

Answer (score 1):

When you see `Num (a -> a)` it generally means you made a mistake somewhere.

Perhaps you really wanted: `abs . sqrt` which has type `Floating c => c -> c` - i.e. it's a function of a Floating type (e.g. Float, Double) to the same Floating type.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not possible to use this function.

What's likely happening here is that the type is saying that `abs(sqrt)` has the constraints that `a` must be of type class `Floating` and `(a -> a)` must be of type class `Num`. In other words, the `sqrt` function needs to be able to be treated as if it was a number.

Unfortunately, `sqrt` is not of type class `Num` so there won't be any input that will work here (not that it would make sense anyway). However, some versions of GHCi allow you to get the type of as if it were possible.

Have a look at [Haskell type length + 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706348/haskell-type-length-1) for a similar type problem.

As ErikR has said, perhaps you meant to write `abs . sqrt` instead.

Comment: Heh, nice template answer